# How to Capitalize a Weird Title

Tags: creative-writing

I've googled and googled this to no avail.

Say I'm making up a weird title for a business like Great Super Wonderful Smart Fancy Famous Hamburger Cafe.

Would I put commas between all these adjectives in a title?

Comment: Is this about commas or capitalization?

Comment: There are no rules for business titles beyond the words deemed mandatory or forbidden by local law.  Do what you like.

Answer (score 0):

In the name of a business you would commonly list the adjectives like you did without comma.

---

Legally some jurisdictions prescribe the characters you can use in a business name. For example, in Delaware you can use the following characters:

capital and lower case letters A-Z, numerals 0-9, and all of the following symbols and punctuation: ! “ ” # $ % & ’ () * + ,- . ? / \ : ;@ { } [ ] ~_^ ` |

But not all entities and systems where a business must enter their business name accepts all those characters. For example, when you register your business with the IRS to obtain a tax identification number, you can only use letters, numbers, hyphens, spaces, and ampersands. These systems usually also only allow a maxium length of a business name. So if you don't want to have to enter some different form of your business name in these systems, you may not want to go too wild with using punctuation or special characters.

Another consideration is the ability for your customers to memorize, write and say your business name. You don't want a name that people cannot remember, don't find when they try to google it, or don't know how to pronounce.

Answer (score 0):

No punctuation is needed.

Punctuation and some rules of grammar can be disregarded as concerns titles. For example, capitalization. The use of commas is similar because they are not necessary for a title.